# immediate translate animation in WPF in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I want to make an animation that involves translating a circle `_fixedCircle` on x-axis from starting point **(5,0)** to end point **(200,0)** and then from  **(200,0)** to **(5,0)**  **In a forever loop** but not following a path, but "jumping", in other words, immediate translation from point to point.

To animate this circle doing a linear interpolation there is this:

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
sb.Children.Add(anim);
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, _fixedCircle);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
anim.From = 5;
anim.To = 200;
anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
anim.AutoReverse = true;
MYCANVAS.Resources.Add("CIRCLE_ID", sb);
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
anim.Duration = duration;
anim.Begin();
```

But how to create "jumping" effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`, adding a `DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame` for each jump you want, e.g. (calculation of jump values has a lot of room for improvement ;)):

```
DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames anim = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

int maxNrOfJumps = 10;
for (int jump = 0; jump < maxNrOfJumps; jump++) {
    double value = ((200 - 5) / maxNrOfJumps) * jump;
    anim.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(value, KeyTime.FromPercent(jump / (double)maxNrOfJumps)));
}
```

> Discrete key frames like DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame create sudden "jumps" between values (no Interpolation). In other words, the animated property does not change until the key frame's key time is reached at which point the animated property goes suddenly to the target value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.discretedoublekeyframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**Edit:**

Running it can be done without a `Storyboard`, this is how I tested it:

```
_fixedCircle.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, anim);
```

**Edit2:**

You'd still need to set these properties to keep the animation running:

```
anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
anim.AutoReverse = true;
```

Also, don't forget to set the `Duration`...

Comment: What to pass as argument to `anim.BeginAnimation(?); ` and most important how to assign this animation to canvas and my circle?

Comment: @cMinor Sorry, I assumed you knew that. See my edit.

Comment: I tried it and it only does one jump, What am I missing so it keeps on jumping from point to point?

Comment: @cMinor Set up the animation as you did in your question, the `RepeatBehavior.Forever` and `AutoReverse` will keep the animation running.

Answer (score 0):

> immediate translation from point to point

Are you looking for a kind of instant teleportation from the first point to the last one ?

If so :

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation();
sb.Children.Add(anim);
Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, _fixedCircle);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
anim.From = 5;
anim.To = 200;
// anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever; // nope
anim.AutoReverse = false; // well
MYCANVAS.Resources.Add("CIRCLE_ID", sb);
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)); // here we go
anim.Duration = duration;
anim.Begin();
```

Comment: I am getting `Error 1 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation' does not contain a definition for 'begin' and no extension method 'begin' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`, but If I chage available method `anim.BeginAnimation()` I am asked to pass a parameter, Would not it be `sb.Begin ();` instead?

Comment: Ok try `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)`. The animation is going to be really fast.

Comment: At this point you can think about the utility of your storyboard.

Comment: Ok,I get it, however your answer Is not quite what I need, If I need the circle to appear and dissapear, lets say from `(5,0) -> (200,0) -> (5,0) -> (200,0) ` it will seem that circle is running from poitn to point and not teleporting... How to adapt your code so circle appears and dissapears to those points?

Comment: You want to bounce or to wink/flash ? For the second, you should add again the RepeatBehavior : `anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;`.

Comment: I also set autoReverse to true, and Added `anim.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;` but circle seems to run and not jump or teleport... It follows a line

Comment: Can you build a small project? I will try it.

Comment: well I think I solve it in a different way, I created 2 circles and then animate/alternate their opacity. Seems to be great progress. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `skipToFill` property?
just add it to your `storyboard`.

Comment: Could you please post an example where circle skips from one point to other point and then returns?

Comment: I guess I could use skipToFill  and then stop animation and then restart animation

Comment: Or you could just use skipToFill and add a completed event.